# Simple ES6 TODO list

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dom, to-do-list

This is how my app looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

I can add and remove tasks, mark them as complete, move them up and down on a list, and filter them.

I have few questions about some parts of my code that I'm pasting here.

First thing that concerns me is that in addTask() function I have tons of document.createElement one by one and it looks like a wall of code. Is this ok?

Second thing that makes me wonder is that in the same function (addTask) I am appending many things and it feels like I am repeating myself. Is there a cleaner solution?

My third question is about editTask() function. I feel it needs lots of improvement, but I don't really know how to do it. For example two lines are setting my inputButton.style. Should I move them to CSS file and set style just to get one line of code less?

Of course if there are any mistakes please point them out!

```
const vApp = {

addTask: () => {
    const taskText = document.getElementById('newTask'),
        contentBox = document.getElementById('tasksholder'),
        taskCreator = document.createElement('div'),
        textBox = document.createElement('div'),
        deleteButton = document.createElement('button'),
        editButton = document.createElement('button'),
        downButton = document.createElement('button'),
        upButton = document.createElement('button'),
        checkBox = document.createElement('input'),
        label = document.createElement('label');

    if (taskText.value.length > 0) {        // protection against empty input
        taskCreator.className = 'task-box';
        textBox.innerHTML = taskText.value;
        textBox.className = 'textBox';
        contentBox.insertBefore(taskCreator, contentBox.childNodes[0]);
        taskText.value = '';                // clear input box

        deleteButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/delete.png')";
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            contentBox.removeChild(this.parentNode);
        });

        editButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/edit.png')";
        editButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            vApp.disableEditing(this.parentNode, true);
            vApp.editTask(this.parentNode);
        });

        downButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/down.png')";
        downButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (this.parentNode ===  contentBox.lastChild) {
                return false;
            } else {
                vApp.swapElements(this.parentNode, this.parentNode.nextSibling);
            }
        });

        upButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/up.png')";
        upButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (this.parentNode ===  contentBox.firstChild) {
                return false;
            } else {
                vApp.swapElements(this.parentNode, this.parentNode.previousSibling);
            }
        });

        checkBox.type = "checkbox";
        checkBox.addEventListener('click', function() {
           vApp.manageCheckbox(this.parentNode);
        });

        label.appendChild(checkBox);
        taskCreator.appendChild(textBox);
        taskCreator.appendChild(label);
        taskCreator.appendChild(downButton);
        taskCreator.appendChild(upButton);
        taskCreator.appendChild(editButton);
        taskCreator.appendChild(deleteButton);
        taskText.placeholder = 'What else needs to be done?';

    } else {
        vApp.warn();
    }
},

disableEditing: (buttonParent, enabling) => {
    buttonParent.childNodes[4].disabled = enabling;
},

editTask: (taskToEdit) => {
    const bubble = document.createElement('span'),
        inputField = document.createElement('input'),
        inputButton = document.createElement('button'),
        textContainer = document.createElement('div');

    inputField.value = taskToEdit.innerText;
    inputField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    inputField.setAttribute('maxlength', '40');
    taskToEdit.removeChild(taskToEdit.firstChild);
    textContainer.className = 'textBox';
    bubble.className = 'bubble';
    inputButton.innerText = 'Ok';
    inputButton.style.fontSize = '18px';
    inputButton.style.color = "#dddddd";
    inputButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        textContainer.innerHTML = inputField.value;
        taskToEdit.insertBefore(textContainer, taskToEdit.childNodes[0]);
        vApp.disableEditing(taskToEdit,false);
        bubble.parentNode.removeChild(bubble);
    });
    bubble.appendChild(inputField);
    bubble.appendChild(inputButton);
    taskToEdit.appendChild(bubble);
},


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want, you can always refactor functions like `document.getElementById()` so that you type less. Something that I see a lot of people do is:

   ```
   const E = id => document.getElementById(id);

   ...

   const taskText = E('newTask'),
   ...
   ```
2. Same thing for `document.createElement()`:

   ```
   const Element = tag => document.createElement(tag);
   ```
3. Anything involving styles should probably be in an external CSS stylesheet.
4. You can paste your HTML into the question and make a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so that we can try out your application.

Comment: Is 1. and 2. really a good practice? It seems like making code less verbal.

Comment: JavaScript is VERY verbal, almost too verbal when it comes to this. You can choose a different name for the alias to make it more readable to you if you want.